# replace null sql with 0

Tags: sql

```
Select t.a,sum(s.value) e, sum(r.value) i
CASE when e is NULL then '0' else i end 
from table1 t
LEFT JOIN table2 s
ON t.name = s.in
LEFT JOIN table2 r
ON t.name = r.out
group by a
ORDER BY a
```

My query has error state like 42601, how can i solve this problem to replacing null values with '0'?

Comment: what? can you explain what is the needed outcome of your query?

Comment: How about using isNull(value, valueIfNull)? See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: ISNULL is product specific, use COALESCE instead.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the `ALIAS` in the same level it was created. You have to use the aggregated form:

```
Select  t.a,
        sum(s.value) e, 
        sum(r.value) i,
        CASE when sum(s.value) is NULL then 0 else sum(r.value) end 
from table1 t 
    LEFT JOIN table2 s ON t.name = s.in 
    LEFT JOIN table2 r ON t.name = r.out 
group by a 
ORDER BY a
```

Otherwise, wrap it in a subquery if you still wanted to use `ALIAS`

```
SELECT  a, e, i,
        CASE when e is NULL then 0 else i end
FROM
    (
        Select  t.a,
                sum(s.value) e, 
                sum(r.value) i 
        from table1 t 
            LEFT JOIN table2 s ON t.name = s.in 
            LEFT JOIN table2 r ON t.name = r.out 
        group by a 
    ) subquery
ORDER BY a
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ISNULL`

```
Select t.a,sum(ISNULL(s.value,0)) e, sum(r.value) i
from table1 t
LEFT JOIN table2 s
ON t.name = s.in
LEFT JOIN table2 r
ON t.name = r.out
group by a
ORDER BY a
```

Comment: `ISNULL()` is a product specific function. The question has no dbms specified.